# PostGIS ST_Contains failing to return data

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm encountering a strange case using PostGIS 2.1.7 with PostgreSQL 9.4.

I'm trying to match a point that's located within California (latitude : 36.671112, longitude : -121.662636, as we can see on this map : https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=zHggIvE-1G0A.kW1YFh5cNOJU&usp=sharing) with the following query :

```
select name
from zones
where ST_Contains(area, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-121.662636, 36.671112), 4326))
```

where `zones` is defined as below :

```
create table zones (
  name text,
  kml text,
  area geometry
)

insert into zones (name, kml)
values (
  'California',
  '<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-118.603375,33.478098,0 -118.60403,33.47654,0 -118.601185,33.469853,0 -118.593969,33.467198,0 -118.575901,33.448261,0 -118.570927,33.439351,0 -118.563442,33.434381,0 -118.558715,33.433419,0 -118.53738,33.434608,0 -118.52323,33.430733,0 -118.516267,33.425075,0 -118.515914,33.422417,0 -118.503952,33.424234,0 -118.48875,33.419826,0 -118.484949,33.412131,0 -118.478465,33.38632,0 -118.482609,33.369914,0 -118.48877,33.356649,0 -118.481886,33.344123,0 -118.465368,33.326056,0 -118.456309,33.32182,0 -118.440047,33.318638,0 -118.402941,33.320901,0 -118.374768,33.320065,0 -118.360332,33.31533,0 -118.343249,33.305234,0 -118.325244,33.299075,0 -118.316787,33.301137,0 -118.305084,33.310323,0 -118.303174,33.320264,0 -118.310213,33.335795,0 -118.316083,33.342928,0 -118.32446,33.348782,0 -118.365094,33.388374,0 -118.368301,33.40711,0 -118.370323,33.409285,0 -118.382037,33.409883,0 -118.423576,33.427258,0 -118.445812,33.428907,0 -118.477646,33.448392,0 -118.48557,33.446213,0 -118.499669,33.447879,0 -118.500212,33.449592,0 -118.530702,33.468071,0 -118.54453,33.474119,0 -118.585936,33.473819,0 -118.598783,33.477939,0 -118.603375,33.478098,0 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>'
)

update zones
set area = ST_GeomFromKML(kml)
```

Here's what's returned :

```
 name 
------
(0 row)
```

Although it should have returned this instead :

```
   name 
-----------
California
(1 row)
```

Do you see anything wrong with the query or the table creation script ?

(I've to say that this is not an edge case related to the point itself since I've encountered the same problem with over 60 000 different points, all located within California)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not returning a match because the point is not inside that zone.

Try this query:

```
select st_xmax(area), st_ymax(area), st_xmin(area), st_ymin(area) from zones;
```

You'll see that the point is well outside the the max and min points:

```
"st_xmax","st_ymax","st_xmin","st_ymin"
-118.303174,33.478098,-118.60403,33.299075
```

Your zone appears to be one island off the coast of Los Angeles (there's a town called "Avalon" on this island) and not the entire State.

(Little tip for you. You can use a GIS like QGIS to visualise your layers - you'd soon see the problem. That's what I did!).